# Python regular expression for extracting value of a key

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract value from a key=value pair (String) in Python, using regular expression (re.compile and match). I am new to Python. Any help appreciated...

Ex String:
`[INFO] LICENSE=abcd-efgh-1234-34ki`
I want the value of LICENSE i.e `abcd-efgh-1234-34ki`

I tried the below, but it is not exactly working

```
license_regex = re.compile('.*LICENSE=.*?.*')
    match = license_regex.match(line)
```

`=>` prints the whole line.
then I tried with `(.*?)!.*' =>` doesn't print anything

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you provide what you have tried so far, as well as any errors you're getting?

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com/, switch it to Python mode, insert your sample text and work on your regex. There are tons of examples all over the Internet how regex is used in Python. Try reading some. If you have a specific question, you are welcome to ask it. As it stands, this is not a specific question, but a coding assignment.

Comment: There is no point to use a regex here. Splittng with `=` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
^.*?\bLICENSE=(.*)
```

then the captured group will have the desired portion.

- `^.*?` lazily matches upto a empty string followed by `LICENSE=`
- `(.*)` matches the rest, and put in captured group 1

**Example:**

```
In [2]: s = '[INFO] LICENSE=abcd-efgh-1234-34ki'

In [3]: re.search(r'^.*?\bLICENSE=(.*)', s).group(1)
Out[3]: 'abcd-efgh-1234-34ki'
```

Comment: If it worked, why not [use a simple `split`](http://ideone.com/OKVA1J)? `s.split('LICENSE=')[1]` or `s.split('=')[1]` are way more efficient.